Unable to reserve BAR in PCI device
I'm writing a low-level kernel module that would interface a parallel port via PCIe socket. The card uses Axis AX99100 chip. The listing of a device using lspci -v -s 29:00.2 results in the following output:
Parallel controller: Asix Electronics Corporation AX99100 PCIe to Multi I/O Controller (prog-if 03 [IEEE1284])
Subsystem: Asix Electronics Corporation (Wrong ID) Parallel Port
Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 39, IOMMU group 26
I/O ports at c010 [size=8]
I/O ports at c000 [size=8]
Memory at fc601000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at fc600000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel modules: parport_pc


While trying to reserve I/O ports for my module I get denied from doing so.
Using sudo lsmod | grep parport to inspect and remove all parallel drivers that could possibly use this card's parallel I/O. And in terms of privileges, my module is build and loaded using root privileges.
After loading my module and running the lspci -v -s 29:00.2 again I would additionally see the following line:
Kernel driver in use: pci-test-driver

Which means my driver is now bound to this device. Yet, neither of BARs couldn't be reserved using the pci_request_region() function from the <linux/pci.h> linux header.
For additional insight the code of my module is shown below.
#include <linux/pci.h>         // Core PCI functions and structures
#include <linux/pci_regs.h>    // PCI configuration space register definitions
#include <linux/init.h>        // Macros used for module initialization
#include <linux/module.h>      // Macros for module management
#include <linux/kernel.h>      // Core kernel functionality
#include <linux/io.h>          // Memory-mapped I/O functions
#include <linux/interrupt.h>   // Functions for handling interrupts

#define PCI_TEST_VENDOR_ID 0x125b //0x144d
#define PCI_TEST_DEVICE_ID 0x9100 //0xa808

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("PCIe Driver");
MODULE_AUTHOR("BMW");

static struct pci_device_id pci_ids[] = {
    { PCI_DEVICE(PCI_TEST_VENDOR_ID, PCI_TEST_DEVICE_ID), },
    { 0, }
};

MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(pci, pci_ids);

static int pci_probe(struct pci_dev *pdev, const struct pci_device_id *ent);
static void pci_remove(struct pci_dev *pdev);
static int read_config_space(struct pci_dev *pdev);
static int read_mmio_space(struct pci_dev *pdev);

static struct pci_driver pci_driver = {
    .name = "pci-test-driver",
    .id_table = pci_ids,
    .probe = pci_probe,
    .remove = pci_remove
};

struct parport_dev {
    struct pci_dev *pdev;
    void __iomem *bar0_addr;
};

static int pci_probe(struct pci_dev *pdev, const struct pci_device_id *ent) {
    pr_info("Probing device: vendor=0x%X, device=0x%X\n", pdev->vendor, pdev->device);
    
    struct parport_dev *parport;
    int err;

    // Supports multiple probe() calls, nvme struct must persist until removal
    parport = kzalloc(sizeof(parport), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (parport == NULL) {
        pci_disable_device(pdev);
        pr_err("Failed to allocate memory for parport struct!\n");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    pci_set_drvdata(pdev, parport);
    nvme->pdev = pdev;

    // Reserve BAR0 for this driver
    err = pci_request_region(pdev, 0, "parport_driver");
    if (err) {
        kfree(parport);
        pci_disable_device(pdev);
        dev_err(&pdev->dev, "Failed to request BAR0\n");
        return err;
    }

    // Map parallel port memory into kernel managed memory
    parport->bar0_addr = pci_ioremap_bar(pdev, 0);
    if (parport->bar0_addr == NULL) {
        pci_release_regions(pdev);
        kfree(parport);
        pci_disable_device(pdev);
        dev_err(&pdev->dev, "Failed to map BAR0\n");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    dev_info(&pdev->dev, "Mapped BAR0 at %p\n", parport->bar0_addr);    

    return 0;
}

static void pci_remove(struct pci_dev *pdev) {
    pr_info("Removing device: vendor=0x%X, device=0x%X\n", pdev->vendor, pdev->device);
    pci_disable_device(pdev);
}

static int __init pci_init(void) {
    int ret;

    pr_info("pci-test module init");

    // Register the PCI driver
    ret = pci_register_driver(&pci_driver);
    if (ret) {
        pr_err("Failed to register PCI driver\n");
        return ret;
    }

    return 0;
}

static void __exit pci_exit(void) {
    pr_info("pci-test module exit");
    pci_unregister_driver(&pci_driver);
}

module_init(pci_init);
module_exit(pci_exit);

The following log is the output of the sudo dmesg command and shows a response when all of available BARs try to be reserved:
[ 2827.501937] pci-test-driver 0000:29:00.2: BAR 0: can't reserve [io  0xc010-0xc017]
[ 2827.501940] pci-test-driver 0000:29:00.2: Failed to request BAR0
[ 2827.501942] pci-test-driver 0000:29:00.2: BAR 1: can't reserve [io  0xc000-0xc007]
[ 2827.501944] pci-test-driver 0000:29:00.2: Failed to request BAR1
[ 2827.501946] pci-test-driver 0000:29:00.2: BAR 2: can't reserve [mem 0xfc601000-0xfc601fff]
[ 2827.501949] pci-test-driver 0000:29:00.2: Failed to request BAR2
[ 2827.501950] pci-test-driver 0000:29:00.2: BAR 5: can't reserve [mem 0xfc600000-0xfc600fff]
[ 2827.501952] pci-test-driver 0000:29:00.2: Failed to request BAR5

